# Propel - how can I set column name for PHP same as in DB automatically

Tags: propel

I used Propel 2 and want to have the column-names for PHP just the same like they are in dhe DB. I used a schema.xml like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<database name="timetable" defaultIdMethod="native">
 <table name="entry" phpName="Entry">
  <column name="id" type="integer" required="true" primaryKey="true" autoIncrement="true" />
  <column name="date" type="date"  required="true" />
  <column name="timeBegin" phpName="timeBegin" type="time"  required="true" />
  <column name="timeEnd" type="time" required="true" />
  <column name="description" type="varchar" size="128" required="true" />
  <column name="expert_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
  <column name="project_id" type="integer" required="true"/>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="expert" phpName="Expert" refPhpName="Entry">
   <reference local="expert_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
  <foreign-key foreignTable="project" phpName="Project" refPhpName="Entry">
   <reference local="project_id" foreign="id"/>
  </foreign-key>
 </table>
</database>
```

Propel generates by this the names for the tables and columns. The names in the mySQL-database are written in the correct manner, just as described in the schema.xml. But by default Propel generates the names for the columns in PHP with a capital letter and everything behind is a lowercase. This is not what I want, I got for example "**T**ime**e**nd" instead of "**t**ime**E**nd"
Look at this easy query:

```html
<?php
 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 include "generated-conf/config.php";
 
 $entry = EntryQuery::create()
 ->find()
 ->exportTo('JSON');
 
 echo $entry;
```

It produces:
`{"Entries":{"Entry_0":{"Id":1,"Date":"11.09.2015","timeBegin":"09:00","Timeend":"19:00","Description":"","ExpertId":5,"ProjectId":7}}}`
What I want is this: **i**d, **d**ate, **t**ime**B**egin, **t**ime**E**nd, **d**escription, **e**xpertId, **p**rojectId (or expert_id, project_id).
I know that I can force Propel to do this by using for every column phpName="timeBegin" and so on (like I do just for demonstraiting in the example above), but I find this to inconvenient. This should be possible by some settings perhaps in the propel.xml

Answer (score 1):

You can use the toArray method to return with the column names.

```
$entry = EntryQuery::create()
    ->find()
    ->toArray(null, null, \Propel\Runtime\Map\TableMap::TYPE_FIELDNAME);
```

You can see a snippet here:

http://sandbox.propelorm.org/46731f6

The resulting JSON's root is a bit different, but I'm sure you can work around that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an regex to fix the schema.xml to remove the phpName atribute only for columns

search:

`phpName="(\w)*" type`

replace:
 `type`

Then  rebuild  your models....

`model:build`

An ugly side effect you will have is the getter/setter methods turns into this...

`$object->getid();
$object->gettimebegin();`